# Manipulating forms programmatically

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Is it possible to use the CrmService or the MetadataService to add columns to the various forms that are available in Dynamics? I'm using CreateEntityRequest to create entities and it's working fine but I would like to be able to have all attributes appear on the Default Public View and the Form View without me having to add them using the Dynamics web frontend.

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can get the formxml from the organizationui entity. If you want the published formxml, make sure to pull back the organizationui record whose inproduction attribute is true.

Comment: Thanks Polshgiant. I'll have a look into that.